# Is anyone aware of a good Dictionary/Lexicon style book to help expand a person's Hebrew/Yeshivish vocabulary?

Tags: jewish-books, torah-study, language, adult-learning

I was curious if a good book existed which broke down common phrases or words related to religious practice and observance. Say a dictionary but it defines common phrases in observance.

Example:

**Mi sheberach** - *a public prayer or blessing for an individual or group, most often recited in synagogue when the Torah is being read.*

Basically a book broken down in this sort of format.

Comment: There's this website online, but it's not at all exhaustive: http://www.jewish-languages.org/jewish-english-lexicon/

Comment: "The Joys of Yiddish" by Rosten has some of the "Yinglish" terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

[Frumspeak: The First Dictionary of Yeshivish](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568216149) by Chaim Weiser.

Comment: It's a Yeshivish dictionary, so words like "Mi Shebeirach" might not be in there. Words like "mamish", "bavorn", and "drush" will.

Answer (score 1):

We have one [right here on Mi Yodeya Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/581/9682). It has some Yeshivish terminology you might find flung around the site, but also terms like your Mi Shebeirach example which describe different practices in general. It’s certainly not exhaustive, but it’s a good start.